# Several login succeeded in SQL Server ERRORLOG file

Tags: sql-server, ado

Is this normal to have in SQL Server errorlog file one login succeeded every 10-15 ms ?

Our software use ADO to access to SQL Database. ADO connection is create once while application running and closed when application closed. Is query execution add this line in log ?

The database is in simple recovery mode and autoclose off.

> Examples of errorlog :
>
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.46 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.50 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.53 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.57 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.61 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.64 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.68 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.72 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.75 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.79 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.83 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.87 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.91 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.94 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:23.98 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:24.02 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:24.05 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
> 2017-05-04 18:34:24.09 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'userSQL'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]

Thanks to help me to understand if it is normal or not

Comment: Why should it *not* be normal? How many users are connecting? Is this a desktop application or a web site?

Comment: Using a single connection for a long time is **not** normal though. It will only result in delays and blocking due to the accumulation of shared locks and the occasional missed transaction. OLEDB, ADO and ADO.NET after it support connection pooling so you can close a connection immediatelly after use, releasing server resources, and not pay any penalty to reopen it.

Comment: This is a desktop application and only one user. Severals queries are executed while launching and my question is : is this line is write every queries executed or do we have a connection problem ?

Comment: Impossible to answer without any code.

Comment: If you want to see what is going on, use SQL Server Profiler or Extended events to see what is actually executed. Logon event aren't useful

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly normal.AFAIK, you can turn of this logging as well.please see below screenshot for details

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response but my answer was why ? and not how disable login auditing !!

Comment: @user1069516 asking why without providing any code or details about what the application does, won't get you answers. At least use SQL Server Profiler to see what gets executed.